# Gitlist style git description

Tags: html, css, git, gitlist

I installed [gitlist](http://gitlist.org/) on my developer server and i am trying to style the git description file of a git repository.
I tried to inject html code inside the description file but this is not recognized as html but as text.
After that, i tried to find and edit the php file of gitlist which is not allowing me to style the description file, but i didn't found something.
Is there anyone who could help me?

[git-description-style http://dev.siggouroglou.gr/git-description-problem.png](http://dev.siggouroglou.gr/git-description-problem.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [GitList homepage](http://gitlist.org/):

> GitList is free and open source software, written in PHP, on top of [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) and the [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) template engine.

Twig is often deployed [with its `escaper` extension enabled](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#escaper-extension), which is a relatively safe default setting. With this setting enabled, any text put into Twig templates will be escaped by default, e.g. HTML escaping will turn `<` into `&lt;`. This extension also supports JavaScript escaping.

While this setting is enabled (and I recommend keeping it enabled), you can use [the `raw` filter in templates to disable escaping of certain elements](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html). This will require modifying the template code.

Assuming your description is in a variable called `description`, something like this in the appropriate template should do the trick:

```
{{ description|raw }}
```

Note that permitting raw output does decrease your security. Make sure you trust your users not to put anything harmful into their repository descriptions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I run 'grep -r "description" /var/www/gitlist/* | more' and found that the file i want to edit is the "/var/www/gitlist/cache/views/51/d9/8b4cd3697b50e55e1178ada1e918.php". I edited the line 68 and fix it.

Comment: Glad it helped! But I think you've modified a cached, compiled template. You probably want to modify something like `themes/default/twig/index.twig` or `themes/bootstrap3/twig/index.twig`, depending on what theme you are using.

Comment: Thank you again for your comment. Now i edit a file in views/index.twig. There was a row with "<p>{{ repository.description }}</p>" and i replaced it with "<p>{{ repository.description|raw }}</p>" depending on your answer. The command : grep -r "description" /var/www/gitlist/* | grep "themes" returned nothing.